# color environments influence spacing

Tags: spacing, color

I would like to mark revised parts of a large document in color, and up to now always used

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\rev[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

to then do

```
Lorem ipsum dolor \rev{git} amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
```

This works well, but unfortunately influences the placement of glyphs sometimes, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{amsmath}                                                        
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\rev[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}

AV\\
\rev{A}V

\begin{align}
&U \oplus V\\
&U \rev{\oplus} V
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image: AV spacing]
[image: oplus spacing]

What is a better way of coloring parts of a document?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that `\oplus` is math, whereas your defined color is using `\textcolor`, which is used for text... but that's just my guess

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85035/31034

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Color is implemented via whatsits (`\special`, `\pdfliteral`). These will destroy the implicit kerning as shown in the example with `AV`.

   LuaTeX provides a way for a complete different implementation of color via attributes and not via whatsits. Package `luacolor` goes this new way.
2. The problem in math is different. LaTeX implements colors via grouping. The color is set at the start of the group and reset after the group via `\aftergroup`. However `\textcolor` uses curly braces instead of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`. Curly braces have a side effect in math, they form a subformula with `\mathord` spacing like ordinary symbols. See the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85035/16967), which is cited already in the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183471/color-environments-influence-spacing/183496#comment422866_183471) from ferahfeze.

The example of the question will work, if both package `luacolor` and using `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` instead of curly braces are used:

```
% lualatex
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\newcommand\rev[1]{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color{red}%
    #1%
  \endgroup
}
 
\begin{document}

AV\\
\rev{A}V
%
\begin{align*}
&U \oplus V\\
&U \rev{\oplus} V
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Refinement for package `xspace`

`\xspace` detects `}` (via `\egroup`) and suppresses the space. But `\endgroup` is not detected. The following refinement uses `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` only in math mode, where spaces does not matter:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\newcommand*{\rev}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rev}[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \begingroup
      \color{red}%
      #1%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \textcolor{red}{#1}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

AV\\
\rev{A}V
%
\begin{align*}
&U \oplus V\\
&U \rev{\oplus} V
\end{align*}

\newcommand{\X}{X\xspace}
\X Y\\
\rev{\X} Y\\
$\X Y$\\
$\rev{\X} Y$

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result xspace]

Comment: That't much better. Great post. And good to read that it does not work in pdfLaTeX... got a bit frustrated when searching for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I fear, the "AV" case is too complicated. LaTeX does not kern over the brackets. It wouldn't do a kern between different fonts (emphasized, bold...), too. You can do some reading [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31078). Quite difficult and I didn't manage to solve your case. I hope, the marking of just one single letter is not that often in your work. If it really disturbs you, you will have to add a manual kerning to it.

For the math case, you have to ensure that the colouring does not change your highlight from math- to textmode. I added this solution below. 
I hope, there will be a better solution around, but I got the feeling, that you should ask a second question here on how to kern `\textcolor{red}{V}A` and `\textcolor{red}{AV}A` correctly.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}                                                        
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\rev}[1]{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color{red}#1%
  \endgroup
    }

\begin{document}
\centering
AV\\
\rev{A}\kern-0.26ex V
\begin{align}
&U \oplus V\\
&U \rev{\oplus} V
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]