# math mode coloring

Tags: math-mode, color

I want to color some of the symbols in math mode, but not their subscripts. However, when I do this, the subscripts are broken and escapes from the text.

I have prepared a minimal example to demonstrate my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

$T_i$

${\color{red}T}_i$

$\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{T}_{i}$

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Note that, T and i are separated when T is colored. Is there a way to color properly without adding extra space on the subscript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [obtain the same kerning after coloring as without coloring in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358496/obtain-the-same-kerning-after-coloring-as-without-coloring-in-math-mode)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of changing colors or closing a group immediately before a subscript, change the color after entering the subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
$T_i$

${\color{red}T_{\color{black}i}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's best to wrap the subscript in another `{}` in this case, see [color - Colored sub and super-scripts are misaligned - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16369/colored-sub-and-super-scripts-are-misaligned#comment1561950_16369)

Answer (score 8):

You can remember the current color and use `xparse` for grabbing the possible subscript and superscript, which are typeset in the current color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\colornucleus}{omme{_^}}{%
  \begingroup\colorlet{currcolor}{.}%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
   {\textcolor[#1]{#2}}
   {\textcolor{#2}}
    {%
     #3% the nucleus
     \IfValueT{#4}{_{\textcolor{currcolor}{#4}}}% subscript
     \IfValueT{#5}{^{\textcolor{currcolor}{#5}}}% superscript
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}

$T_i$ $T^j$ $T_i^j$

$\colornucleus{red}{T}_i$
$\colornucleus{red}{T}^j$
$\colornucleus{red}{T}_i^j$

$\colornucleus[rgb]{1,0,0}{T}_{i}$
$\colornucleus[rgb]{0,1,0}{T}^j$
$\colornucleus[rgb]{0,0,1}{T}_{i}^j$

\textcolor{blue!30!red}{Text $\colornucleus{black}{T}_i$ text}

\end{document}
```

[image]