# How can I put all expressions within a pair of dollar signs into a desired color?

Tags: math-mode, color

In my Tex document, I want to colour all the expressions within two dollar signs (such as `$e^{i\pi}$`, `$\log x$` etc), within a pair of dollar signs (such as `$$e^{i\pi}+1=0$$`), within the `\begin{eqnarray}...\end{eqnarray}` in a desired color (say, yellow) without doing it each time. Is there any command to achieve this?

Comment: Probably [How put color in all math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211780/134144) is related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy with `\everymath`.Note that doesn't change the equation numbers colour, bur it can easily be changed with the `\newtagform` command from `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{mathcolour}{red}
\everymath{\color{mathcolour}}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some more text. $T_i$ \quad $\mathbf e^{i\pi}$

\colorlet{mathcolour}{DeepSkyBlue}
\begin{align}
a & = \bm{b} \\
c & = \bm{d}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bernard As far as the dollars are concerned, it is okay. Why it doesn't work for "align environment" or "eqnarray environment"? For "align environment" do we have to repeat the command separately every time?

Comment: ??? My example shows it works for align. I even could change the colour. I didn't test  eqnarray, as I never use it – it produces bad spacing at the alignment points. Do you use a standard class?

Comment: I am an occasional user. I think it does work now. Thanks :-)

Comment: This solution can have lots of unwanted consequences. See [\everymath and author color](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/100263) for discussion. The suggested duplicate it probably a better way.

Comment: I see. Didn't know this (personally I don't colour systematically  equations). Thanks for  the information. Can we say that, if used, it should be so with the utmost caution?

Comment: @Bernard Well it's a solution that will have effects that aren't easy to predict, So in addition to the `\author` issue, all `minipage` and  `tabular` environments will be coloured, as will footnote numbers for example. Frank's solution in the question I linked to solves the first two,  but not the footnote numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[math mode coloring](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415152/math-mode-coloring)

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
$T_i$

${\color{red}T_{\color{black}i}}$
${\color{blue}e^{i\pi}}$
\end{document}
```

**edit**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\everymath{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
    $T_i$
    
    ${T_{i}}$
    ${\color{blue}e^{i\pi}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I want a command that all the expressions inside $...$ are automatically colored by a single command at the beginning of the document.

Comment: @mithusengupta123  please see edit from --  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211780/how-put-color-in-all-math-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @jsbibra The `\everymath` solution is not really viable.  See comments on  the other answer.